# Error while updating data: near "WHERE": syntax error

Tags: python, sqlite, tkinter

I'm coding a student management program with tkinter for gui and sqlite for the database, and i get this error when i try to uptade an info (im a junior, sorry for the messy code lol, and texts might seem weird its because i translated it):

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.2288.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1967, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\berat\Desktop\Ogrenci_kayit_sistemi\test.py", line 431, in update_response
    update_record();
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\berat\Desktop\Ogrenci_kayit_sistemi\test.py", line 422, in update_record
    cursor.execute(update_query, updated_values + [result[0]])
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "WHERE": syntax error
```

That error occurs here:

```
    def update_record():
        updated_values = [var.get() for var in entry_vars]
        


        update_query = "UPDATE students SET {} WHERE id = ?".format(
            ", ".join(f"{column[0]} = ?" for column in cursor.description if column[0] != "photo")
        )

        cursor.execute(update_query, updated_values + [result[0]])
        conn.commit()
        result_window.destroy()


    def update_response():
        response_update = messagebox.askquestion("confirm", "gonna update")          

        if response_update == "yes":
            update_record();
        
            messagebox.showinfo("info", "success")
        
        elif response_update == "no":
            messagebox.showinfo("info","cancelled")
```

and here is the all codes that is related to update screen and other methods:

```
def search_student():
    global student_id
    student_id = entry_ara_student_id.get()

    cursor.execute("SELECT id, name, surname, gender, b_date, b_place, phone, adress, student_id, class, section, price, installment, reg_date FROM students WHERE student_id=?",
                    
                   (student_id,)) 
    
    result = cursor.fetchone() 

    if result:
        show_search_result(result)
    else:
        messagebox.showinfo("info", "no data.")
        

def show_search_result(result):
    global photo_update
    result_window = Toplevel(root)
    result_window.title("Data edit")

    

    entry_vars = [] 

    for i, column_name in enumerate(cursor.description): 
        if column_name[0] == "photo": #skipped
            continue
        

        label = Label(result_window, text=column_name[0])
        label.grid(row=2+i, column=0, padx=5, pady=5, sticky="e")

        if column_name[0] in ["id","reg_date","price","installments","student_id"]: 
            var = StringVar(result_window) 
            var.set(result[i])  
            entry = Entry(result_window, width=20, textvariable=var, state='disabled') 


   
        elif column_name[0] in ["gender", "class", "section", "installments"]: 
    
            values = ["Male", "Female"] if column_name[0] == "gender" else list(range(1, 9)) if column_name[0] == "class" else ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"] if column_name[0] == "section" else list(range(1, 9))
            var = StringVar(result_window)
            var.set(result[i]) 
            entry = Combobox(result_window, textvariable=var, values=values, state="readonly")

        else:          
            var = StringVar(result_window)
            var.set(result[i])  
            entry = Entry(result_window, width=20, textvariable=var)

        entry.grid(row=2+i, column=1, padx=5, pady=5, sticky="w")
        entry_vars.append(var)
        
    
    def update_record():
        updated_values = [var.get() for var in entry_vars]
        


        update_query = "UPDATE students SET {} WHERE id = ?".format(
            ", ".join(f"{column[0]} = ?" for column in cursor.description if column[0] != "photo")
        )

        cursor.execute(update_query, updated_values + [result[0]])
        conn.commit()
        result_window.destroy()


    def update_response():
        response_update = messagebox.askquestion("confirm", "gonna update")          

        if response_update == "yes":
            update_record();
        
            messagebox.showinfo("info", "success")
        
        elif response_update == "no":
            messagebox.showinfo("info","cancelled") 

    btn_update = Button(result_window, width=19, text="update record", command=update_response)
    btn_update.grid(row=len(cursor.description)+2, column=0, padx=10, pady=5)

    def delete_record():
        response_delete = messagebox.askquestion("confirm", "gonna delete")

        if response_delete == "yes":
            cursor.execute("DELETE FROM students WHERE id = ?", (result[0],))
            conn.commit()
            result_window.destroy()
            messagebox.showinfo("info", "deleted")

        elif response_delete == "no":
            messagebox.showinfo("info", "cancelled")

    btn_delete = Button(result_window, width=19, text="delete", command=delete_record)
    btn_delete.grid(row=len(cursor.description)+2, column=1, padx=10, pady=5)

    def photo_update():
    
        cursor.execute("SELECT photo FROM students WHERE student_id=?", (student_id,))
        photo_data = cursor.fetchone()


        if photo_data:
            image = Image.open(io.BytesIO(photo_data[0]))
            target_width = 200
            target_height = 200
            resized_image = image.resize((target_width, target_height), Image.BILINEAR)
            photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(resized_image)
            label_photo.config(image=photo)
            label_photo.image = photo
        else:
            label_photo.config(image='')
            label_photo.image = None

    label_photo = Label(result_window)
    label_photo.grid(row=0,column=0,columnspan=2)

    def update_photo():
        file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename()
    
        if file_path: 
            with open(file_path, "rb") as file:
                photo_data = file.read()

            response_update = messagebox.askquestion("confirm", "gonna update")

            if response_update == "yes":
                messagebox.showinfo("info", "success")
                cursor.execute("UPDATE students SET photo=? WHERE student_id=?", (photo_data, student_id))
                conn.commit()

                photo_update() #direkt yeniliyor bu şekilde

            elif response_update == "no":
                messagebox.showinfo("info", "cancelled")

            
    btn_guncelle = Button(result_window, text="update", command=update_photo)
    btn_guncelle.grid(row=1,column=0,columnspan=2, padx=10, pady=5)

label_arama = Label(tab2, text="record update",fg="blue")
label_arama.grid(row=0, column=0,padx=10, pady=5,sticky="w")

label_ara_student_id = Label(tab2, text="student id:")
label_ara_student_id.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=10, pady=5,sticky="e")
entry_ara_student_id = Entry(tab2, width=23)
entry_ara_student_id.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=10, pady=5,columnspan=2)

btn_ara = Button(tab2, width=19, text="Sorgula", command=lambda:[search_student(),photo_update()])
btn_ara.grid(row=2, column=1,padx=10, pady=5,columnspan=2)
```

Comment: What is `result` within `update_record`?  There's no `global` for it in `search_student`, so it can't be that.

Comment: It is the same variable, i made it global (and changed the variable name too, i realized i had couple more "result"s for question methods) but still it can not reach it. @TimRoberts

Comment: Print the output of `update_query` just before the call to `cursor.execute` so you can see exactly what you are trying to execute.

Comment: `updated_values` works, but yeah, `update_query` prints `UPDATE students SET  WHERE id = ?` and i got the same error even i disabled `update_query` and add the code in `cursor_execute` @chepner

Comment: Note *nothing* is inserted between `SET` and `WHERE`. Check the value of `cursor.description`, because it appears not to have any (non-`photo`-related) entries. Basically, you aren't generating the `UPDATE` query you expect. (Or maybe you incorrectly assume that you can update zero columns in an `UPDATE` query. You need at least one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cursor.description` may not be what you want if you have executed `photo_update()` before executing `update_record()`.

Suggest changing `entry_vars` to dictionary instead of list, and use it to build the UPDATE SQL statement instead:

```py
def show_search_result(result):
    ...

    entry_vars = {}  # use dictionary instead of list
    for i, column_name in enumerate(cursor.description):
        ...

        entry_vars[column_name[0]] = var

        def update_record():
            updated_values = [var.get() for var in entry_vars.values()]

            update_query = "UPDATE students SET {} WHERE id = ?".format(
                ", ".join(f"{column} = ?" for column in entry_vars)
            )
            ...

        ...
```